# django select complete single row and print

Tags: python, django, select, row

I want to select a single row completely to print it.

I mean to get `name`, `address`, `city`, `state_province`, `country`, `website`.

And also how I can select some of the column of onw row?

views.py:

```
from books.models import Publisher

def send(request):
    p = Publisher.objects.filter(id='29')
    return render(request, 'style.html', {'items': p})
```

style.html:

```
{{ items }}
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: This is the third question you've asked today with the code in quotes rather than code indenting.... Please edit it to use the code blocks, you can do this easily by highlighting a section of the text and pressing Ctrl+K, otherwise make sure the lines of code start with 5 spaces.

Comment: Please also include what you have tried/researched so far to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you access all the fields of a row in the template.
You use the dot notation on the queryset object to access each field in your template (in your case, **style.html**):

```
{{ items.name }}
{{ items.address }}
{{ items.city }}
{{ items.state_province }}
{{ items.country }}
{{ items.website}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just figured it out myself :D

Thanks to you and this url http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_templates/index.html

Answer (score 0):

### To access all the data from selected object/row in quesryset

**Code:**

```
 Publisher.objects.filter(id='29').all().values()
```

**Output: *"data in the quesryset has been enter manually just to give eg output"***

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 29, 'name': 'xyz', 'address': 'xyz', 'City': 'xyz','state_province':'xyz','country':'xyz','website':'xyz'}]>
```

---

#### To access all the data of the selected objects in the template

> Credit @doru

**style.html**

```
{{ items.name }}
{{ items.address }}
{{ items.city }}
{{ items.state_province }}
{{ items.country }}
{{ items.website}}
```